# How do we address our hair - it or them?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

So i was talking to a friend and had to mention that this is the first time I have let my hair grow so long and going to cut them/it in summer.

What is the correct(grammatically) way to describe the above sentence?

Comment: Hair is like many foods: if you are talking about a specific one, it is countable; but otherwise it is uncountable. (eg _chicken_, _cabbage_.)

Answer (score 2):

Always refer someone's hair, in its totality, as a single unit.

> I had my hair cut.  It was too long.
>
> My hair is getting long.  I should have it cut.

Never refer to someone's hair, in its totality, in the plural.

> I had my hairs cut. No
>
> My hairs are getting long. No
>
> Your hairs are blonde.

Refer to a subset of someone's hair as hairs, a hair, or as hair.

> A hair got in her eye.  (just one)
>
> Some hairs got in her eye.  (many)
>
> Her hair got in her eyes. (an unspecified amount of hair)
>
> The stylist had to go back and cut a few hairs he missed the first time.
>
> I have a hair that grows faster and is longer than the rest of my hair.
>
> You have some blonde hairs in your mustache.  Also acceptable -- You have blonde hair in your mustache (means the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

Your hair is long means all or many of them are long. In the same way you are getting all or many of them cut.

A haircut means having some or all cut just enough to suit the needs of fashion. When telling someone you had a haircut they may attempt a joke by asking "Which one?".

The context will usually make it clear that you are concerned with one or the headful of hair.

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote? Perfectly good answer.

Comment: Not enough detail would be my guess.

Comment: This doesn't address the central question - do you use "it" or "them" when referring to hair.

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity is caused by the fact that hair is the word for the singular strand of hair and also for many strands of hair referred to as a group. Although the second case may seem like a plural, in both cases you are actually referring to a single unit, a strand or a group, so *it* is most appropriate.